# MVVMCross writing on a file stream

Tags: file, stream, mvvmcross

Is there a way in MVVMCross, without creating my own plugin, to open a file stream for writing and/or for reading? The MvxFileStore only supports byte array reading and writing and i could really use some stream handling here to manage big files or streaming encryption.

I am currently using MVVMCross 3.0.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in interface does provide you with two file stream methods - see WriteFile and TryReadBinaryFile in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/File/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File/IMvxFileStore.cs

If these aren't sufficient for you, then you could create and inject your own IStreamFileService implementations - you don't have to do this as a plugin, you can just define them in your platform specific code, and register them in setup.

plugins have reusability advantages, but implementing direct in the UI projects is perfectly acceptable too - whatever your app needs.

Comment: The Link has expired :P